# Fragement replace

Tags: android, android-fragments

Sorry about this level questions,
But I cant figure out how the Fragment work..
I use the default from android studio fragment via ActionBarActivity
and there have error when add R.id.frag_status 
why cant I use this way to replace or add fragment?
How can I replace Fragment1 and Fragment2 into R.id.frag_status when I press button?
Thanks
[image]

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.frag_status, fragment1)
                .commit();
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
public PlaceholderFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
}
```

and activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

fragment_main.xml

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/frag_status"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment1 class

```
package com.fragment.test;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container,false);
    }
}
```

Comment: From what class does Fragment1 inherit?

Comment: Post your fragment1 code and which fragment you are importing?

Comment: thanks, I think you are right, but how can I fix that.
http://i.imgur.com/83nPEkN.png

Comment: Post the **FRAGMENT1** class IMPORTS!

Comment: yes...support v4.app.fregment...
thanks for Vilpe89 and Praveen
I got it!!!

Comment: After I fix fragment1 to inherit support lib, it still said there is no view in FragmentLayout

01-14 08:41:18.761    2182-2182/com.fragment.test E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.fragment.test, PID: 2182
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fragment.test/com.fragment.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f080042 (com.fragment.test:id/frag_status) for fragment Fragment1{29008c5 #0 id=0x7f080042}
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298) ...etc

Comment: frag_status is in your fragment_main.xml

Answer (score 0):

```
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    /*transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.enter_anim, R.animator.exit_anim); This line is for animation in transition.
*/
    transaction.replace(R.id.frag_status, new YourFragment());
    transaction.commit();

    /*
    enter_anim.xml:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set>
         <objectAnimator
             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:duration="1000"
             android:propertyName="x"
             android:valueFrom="2000"
             android:valueTo="0"
             android:valueType="floatType" />
    </set>
    exit_anim.xml:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set>
        <objectAnimator
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:duration="1000"
            android:propertyName="x"
            android:valueFrom="0"
            android:valueTo="-2000"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
    </set>
```